# User specified regions and country collections in Google Charts

Tags: data-visualization, google-visualization

I want to display record counts by country in Google GeoCharts.

However our grouping of countries differs from that used by GeoCharts.

Eg Google uses the UN's:

- North America
- Central America
- South America
- Caribbean

as Subdivisions for America. Our data set is divided into:

- North America
- Latin America

Impedance explosion!

As I see it this means the user loses sight of Mexico when South America is clicked for Latin America. The America chart is too tall and thin and so has to be zoomed out too far to be useful.

Changing our data taxonomy, the countries assigned to a region, is very painful.

**Can I set a user defined region in GeoChart?** Specifying the centre of the map, zoom level, and countries' data to be displayed?

I daresay a grand hack could do this, but it's not a good idea to get out of sync with Goggle's GeoChart code.

I've looked at the new amMaps, but that doesn't seem to be IE7 & 8 compatible.

```
<shakefist at="Microsoft">Argh!</shakefist>
```

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no you can't. You can either pick America, North America, Caribbean, or South America, but not "Latin America". What you could do is create a zooming map, where you show the US, and it will zoom in on a region with click. You actually need to have country data as well as region data, or just have marker data if that's your thing, but here's an example of clicking to zoom:

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart']});

    var width, height, selectedRegion, resolution;

    window.onload = function(){
      width = 556;
      height = 400;
      selectedRegion = 'world';
      resolution = 'subcontinents';
    };

    function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Region');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
      data.addRows([
        [{v:"005", f:"South America"}, 978.7],
        [{v:"011", f:"Western Africa"}, 46],
        [{v:"013", f:"Central America"}, 299],
        [{v:"014", f:"Eastern Africa"}, 63.9],
        [{v:"015", f:"Northern Africa"}, 255.7],
        [{v:"017", f:"Middle Africa"}, 21.4],
        [{v:"018", f:"Southern Africa"}, 244.5],
        [{v:"029", f:"Caribbean"}, 76.5],
        [{v:"030", f:"Eastern Asia"}, 5712.9],
        [{v:"034", f:"Southern Asia"}, 1275.1],
        [{v:"035", f:"South-Eastern Asia"}, 639.2],
        [{v:"039", f:"Southern Europe"}, 777.8],
        [{v:"053", f:"Australia and New Zealand"}, 272],
        [{v:"054", f:"Melanesia"}, 6.3],
        [{v:"057", f:"Micronesia"}, 1.8],
        [{v:"061", f:"Polynesia"}, 1],
        [{v:"143", f:"Central Asia"}, 170.3],
        [{v:"145", f:"Western Asia"}, 834.1],
        [{v:"151", f:"Eastern Europe"}, 1587.6],
        [{v:"154", f:"Northern Europe"}, 801.5],
        [{v:"155", f:"Western Europe"}, 1456.2],
        [{v:"021", f:"Northern America"}, 4704.1]
      ]);

      var options = {
        displayMode: 'regions',
        enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
        resolution: resolution,
        region: selectedRegion,
        height: height,
        width: width
      };

      var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));

      google.visualization.events.addListener(geochart, 'select', function() {
        var selection = geochart.getSelection();

        if (selection.length == 1) {
          var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
          selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
          resolution = "countries";
          options.region = selectedRegion;
          options.resolution = resolution;
          //alert(resolution);
          geochart.draw(data, options);
          }
      });

      geochart.draw(data, options);
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste in to Google Playground (I don't know why this won't work on jsfiddle, I assume it has to do with the window.onload).

Comment: Thanks, Glad to see you used the f, v (format, value) keys in your example.
It is a tricky issue, I don't know of many datasets that are easily broken up along UN guidelines.

Other issues are is Turkey in Europe or Asia? Russia spans both Europe and Asia. Isn't Singapore too titchy to get selected?

I wasn't fully aware of the issues with mapping to GeoChart; Google has done a good job though.